# How to speed up calls to microsoft graph endpoints?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

We make calls to the groups and users endpoints for Microsoft Graph and they are taking 200+ ms to complete.  The web application making the calls is hosted as an App Service in Azure (South Central US).  For some users we need to make multiple calls per user request and it is slowing down our application significantly.  I have reviewed the best practices and known issues with MS Graph and have found no resolution.  Is caching the only way to speed this up?

Documentation we have reviewed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/best-practices-concept
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues

The endpoints we are seeing this delay with are:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

We have seen the same delay with both HttpClient REST calls and the SDK.  We get the same delay if we make a call for a single user or all users.

Code using HttpClient that takes 200+ ms within an Azure data center:

```
var accessToken = await GetBearerAccessToken();

var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + id;

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
     using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
     {
         request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

         using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
         {
              if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
              {
                   var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                   result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Salesperson>(json);
              }
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. Your question, as it stands today, is _really_ broad and doesn't include any code sample showing what you have already tried and what errors/blockers you encountered.

Comment: Thanks Marc! I added a code example and expanded on the tags.  Please let me know if you think this needs more work.  I have a code sample for the graph SDK as well but I am getting the same results.  I would think this shouldn't take more than 50 ms but maybe I have missed something in the documentation.

Comment: Are you fetching a new token and creating a new HTTP client for each call? HttpClient has a lot of overhead and it isn't recommended to use it that way.

Comment: Here is a great article on the HttpClient issue: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: I'm not sure why you are seeing that kind of performance.  I have a demo console calling using HttpClient from my laptop, on hotel wifi in  India and I am seeing 178ms roundtrip for retrieving a user profile.  You definitely should look into caching the accessToken though.  That will add significant time to processing.

Comment: @DarrelMiller - funny enough a coworkers google sent me to this article and looking at our caching logic on AT was messed up... come to find we utilized some wrapper code from b2c user migration repo and THEY had a logic bomb on the cache: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration/pull/11

Comment: @StephenDowd you are lucky your calls are so relatively fast - I almost consistently get between 1.3 - 3.5 sec response times using the latest version (4.11 currently) of Microsoft.Graph nuget package - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet.  I'm tempted to set these calls up to use a HttpClient (singleton) call and see if the nuget is the bottleneck.  Ironically, it's supposed to take care of stuff like caching auth tokens to talk to MSGraph and I'm sure some other "benefits".